# Visual Web Developer - jQuery Intellisense not showing

Tags: jquery, visual-studio, intellisense, visual-web-developer

I'm trying to follow this tutorial - http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=231&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

I have both the vsdoc file and the main jQuery script files in the same folder, and when I include the jquery file, I get no intellisense when I start typing $(, but I do get intellisense when I include the jquery vsdoc file instead.

Any ideas? I'm expecting vs to automatically load the intellisense from the vsdoc.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check you have the hotfix for visual studio installed.

You can get it here, along with instructions on how to do it:

http://blogs.msdn.com/webdevtools/archive/2008/11/07/hotfix-to-enable-vsdoc-js-intellisense-doc-files-is-now-available.aspx

Comment: This did the trick - I thought I already had the hotfix installed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

all you need to do is make sure you reference the vsdoc file at the top of your custom scripts page:

```
/// <reference path="jquery-1.3.2-vsdoc.js" />
```

since the vsdoc is only needed for development, i keep it somewhere on my machine locally and just reference it in every new project i make. there's no need to include it in your project. just make sure your reference path is accurate.

Comment: I'm not trying to write a custom script though, trying to test it out in a aspx page, following the tutorial

Comment: then include this line right under your `<script>` tag. but you really should abstract your script so that it is reusable...

Comment: ps, that tutorial sucks. try this one: http://mwtech.blogspot.com/2009/05/how-to-get-jquery-intellisense-working.html it got me up and running

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to include the jquery file and reference the vsdoc file.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by reference the vsdoc file? Could you explain a tad more? Thanks!