# Is possible to use jQuery intellisense with classic asp?

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2008, asp-classic, intellisense

I read about jQuery intellisense and couldnt get it working in my classic asps pages.. Is it possible? If it yes what should i do?

I am using VS2008 SP1...

Thanks

Comment: Is it working on ASP.NET web sites?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to install the microsoft hotfix. this has been covered in the following StackOverflow question:

[Visual Web Developer - jQuery Intellisense not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245552/visual-web-developer-jquery-intellisense-not-showing/1245613#1245613)

You can also check this article out:

[JQuery 1.3.2 vsdoc does not produce Visual Studio intellisense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/709713/jquery-1-3-2-vsdoc-does-not-produce-visual-studio-intellisense)

Comment: That still probably won't contain the mentioned hotfix. You can check the patches installed by clicking help->about in the IDE